# Need help str_ireplace using argumen if

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I need help replace my result from json. I have this code:

```
<?php

    $arr = $item['data'];
    print_r(str_ireplace("AA","11",$arr));

?>
```

This code work good if I got result from `$item['data'] = AA` will replace `11`, 
but the problem if result from data is `BB` I want to replace with `22`.

My question is how i can replace if got result data AA = 11, BB = 22, CC = 33..etc.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

Just use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to match the full range from `AA-ZZ` and use [`ord()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) to get the ASCII value of that letter and simply subtract 64 from it and print it 2 times.

```
echo preg_replace_callback("/([A-Z])\\1/", function($m){
    return str_repeat(ord($m[1]) - 64, 2);
}, $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Got solution from my friend, hope someone can use it and improve it..

```
<?php
$arr = $item['data'];
if ($arr == "AA") {
print_r(str_ireplace("AA","11",$arr));
} elseif ($arr == "BB") {
print_r(str_ireplace("BB","22",$arr));
} else {
print_r(str_ireplace("CC","33",$arr));
}
?>
```